# How can I enable snap functionality in Reaper?

Tags: reaper

I just bought reaper and I would love to have when I use the cursor to drag/select items for it to snap to the edges. Sony has a really clear snapping when selecting. I put up a video to show what I mean.

Unfortunately, all the info I have found on snapping is about something else. I select portions of my audio to save as different regions and markers. Without that snapping function, I have to zoom in on the beginning and end and really try and make sure it's on the line which I cut.

Ugh, for such a great software, this kills my workflow. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

There is a section in the manual for changing the snap and grid settings:

http://wiki.cockos.com/wiki/index.php/Snap_and_Grid_Settings